# Installing Vagrant alongside RVM isntalled Ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm, vagrant

How do I install vagrant alongside a specific version of ruby installed using RVM?

I have both 1.8.7 and 1.9.3p429 installed. After using RVM to set my default to 1.9.3 I no longer have vagrant available. I could re-install using "gem install vagrant" but this is out of date and doesn't use the providers options.

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant has shifted to using system packages as of version 1.1. So, how to use vagrant along-side RVM? RVM comes with the ability to wrap executables and run them with a specific ruby/gemset.

```
$ rvm wrapper system --no-prefix /path/to/vagrant
```

Where vagrant is the executable `vagrant` that was installed by your package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of vagrant installer from http://downloads.vagrantup.com/, it puts `vagrant` binary in `/usr/bin/vagrant` which should be always in `PATH`.